# add padding to SVG cursor pointer

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

when drag start I am using SVG image as cursor style, but when i drag drag portion selection start from left-top of the pointer like default pointer(see image). I want pointer point to middle of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

by using

```
cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csv.....") 25 15, auto !important;
```

we can add some margin to cursor pointer.